# How to get the number of complete phage genomes available on ncbi?

Tags: genome, public-databases, phylogenetics, virus

I am looking to establish the total number of complete phage genomes available on NCBI.

I am not looking for any specific type, but want to understand the total diversity available.

How can I perform the search?

Comment: Could you supply more details? What groups of phages? Any in particular? Every phage? The answer depends on what you are looking for.

Comment: The idea is to get the total number of complete phage genomes available on ncbi. So yes, I am not looking for any particular kind, just want to know how many are there.

Comment: That's easy. Please update your question to clarify this point, because its helps the archives.

Comment: Done, thank you for guiding me to make the question better suited for the forum.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Go to the NCBI nuccore database, at https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore
   Copy and paste the search term:

   `(bacterial virus[Organism]) AND (3000:110000[sequence length]) NOT bacteria[Organism]`

You'll get 74583 results.

2. Click on the link `send to` and click the checkbox called `file`.
   It will then download.
3. Check the downloaded file is in `fasta format` with ">" to start the ID.
4. If fasta format is absent, return to the webpage and where it states `summary` switch that to `fasta text`

I can't remember if point 4 is needed.

**Notes**

- Sequence length, I am guessing that all phages are between 3000 and 105000 in length, this is to screen out partial sequences and to minimise  bacteria creeping in to the search. I don't quite understand how a phage can be 105 000bp in length, but you can twiddle these parameters to refine the search.
- @acvill informs us that giant phages greater than >200 kb have been annoated. Thus a separate search is likely required targeting this genome size.

Comment: Anecdotally, `(3000:110000[sequence length])` should capture the vast majority of phage genomes, [though a growing number of huge phages (>200 kb) are being annotated](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-020-2007-4).

Comment: Thank you, that is good expert opinion. I will update the post. I am mystified how a virus can be this size in comparison to their bacterial host genome, but phages are not my thing.

Comment: I did not know you could download all the search results at once as fasta.

Answer (score 2):

How about trying this?

1. Go to https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nucleotide. Then type the following command in the search box. It resulted in 23971 items.

`(bacterial virus[Organism]) AND (complete genome[ti]) NOT shotgun[ti] NOT plasmid[ti] NOT bacteria[Organism]`